# How do I call a method of an other class without creating a new object of the class? c#

Tags: c#, class, text, methods, call

I'm a beginner in c# and I'm working on a small windows forms application, a text editor which can control the text of my `RichTextBox1`. (change font type, font size, etc.) I want to create a Find and Replace Dialog to my project. It has a TextBox (`txtText`), which's text should be examined in `RichTextBox1.Text`, and a "Find" Button (`btnFind`) control. I have the code, which examines and selects the next text in `RichTextBox1.Text` which matches the text of `txtText` after the cursor's location:

```
public void FindNextText(string Text)
{
    int TextSelectionStartIndex;
    int CursorPosition = RichTextBox1.SelectionStart;
    if (RichTextBox1.SelectedText == Text)
    {
        TextSelectionStartIndex= RichTextBox1.Text.IndexOf(Text, CursorPosition + 1);
    }
    else
    {
        TextSelectionStartIndex= RichTextBox1.Text.IndexOf(Text, CursorPosition);
    }
    RichTextBox1.Select(TextSelectionStartIndex, Text.Length);
}
```

The only problem is, that this method is in my `MainForm` class, and the Find button, which's Click event calls this method is in my `FindAndReplaceForm` class.

I've tried this code to call it:

```
public partial class FindAndReplaceForm : Form
{
//...
    private void btnFind_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MainForm mf = new MainForm();
        mf.FindNextText(txtText.Text);
    }
//...
}
```

but if I do so, the new MainForm's method will be called and executed, and nothing will be selected in the original form's `RichTextBox1.Text`.

Can anyone help me how to call this method of the original `MainForm` without creating a new object of the class?
Is it possible without setting `MainForm` to a parent, and `FindAndReplaceForm` to a child form?

Thanks for any kind of help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to call an instance method like `FindNextText` you **always** need an instance of the class.

However this doesn't mean you have to create the instance using `new` each time, that would defeat the purpose of object oriented programming. If your `FindAndReplaceForm` needs a reference to the `MainForm`, which in your cast it clearly does then just add a reference to it, e.g.

```
public class FindAndReplaceForm {
    private readonly MainForm _mainForm;

    public FindAndReplaceForm(MainForm mainForm) {
         if (mainForm == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("mainForm");

        _mainForm = mainForm;

        InitializeComponent();
    }

    [...]
}
```

and when you create that form in one of your `MainForm` methods simply add `this` as a parameter: `var findForm = new FindAndReplaceForm(this);`.

Then you can just call

```
_mainForm.FindNextText(txtText.Text);
```

Alternatively you can also use a property with a public setter in the `FindAndReplaceForm` but personally I prefer the user of constructor.

Comment: Thanks! It works perfect for the form. But there was one more thing I had to add under _mainForm = mainForm: the InitializeComponent() method to load all of the form's controls and components as well, and not just an empty form.

Comment: @Richtenzorg I've added the call to InitializeComponent to the constructor. You should also check the `mainForm` parameter for `null` in the constructor but I've initially omitted that check to make the code shorter.

Answer (score 5):

Make it `static` in a Utils class and pass the RichTextBox as a parameter:

```
public static void FindNextText(RichTextBox rtb, string Text)
{
    int TextSelectionStartIndex;
    int CursorPosition = rtb.SelectionStart;
    ...
}
```

And then you call it like:

```
private void btnFind_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //MainForm mf = new MainForm();
    MyUtilsClass.FindNextText(this.RichTextBox1, txtText.Text);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Declare a delegate in the `FindAndReplace` form and a public property of this delegate type.
When you need to call the FindAndReplace form set this property to the address of your FindNextText method, inside the FindAndReplaceForm test if this property has been set and call the method defined there

```
public partial class FindAndReplaceForm : Form
{
    public delegate void OnFindText(string txtToFind);
    public OnFindText FindText;

    private void btnFind_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(FindText != null)
           FindText(textToSearchFor);
    }
}
```

When you call the FindAndReplace Form use it with

```
FindAndReplaceForm f = new FindAndReplaceForm();
f.FindText += FindNextText;
f.ShowDialog();
```

With this kind of approach you don't couple your `FindAndReplace` form to your main form. You simply defer the execution of the search algorithm to any caller that sets its own handler for the search.